# More conditions in a try/except construct python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a small program with try/except. It should return a mark between A and F for an input value (score) between 0 and 1. When I run it works as it should, i.e.for an input of 0.6 it returns D, for an input of 0.72 it returns C and so on. If I enter a string I get the error printed after the except statement as It should be. But if I type a number higher than 1 (which is out of range (0-1)) I would like to get the same error after the except statement but I get an A. It seems that

```
score_float >=0.0 and score_float <= 1.0
```

does not work. How could I solve it? Thanks

Here is the script:

```
 score = raw_input('Enter score: ')

try:
    score_float = float(score)
    score_float >=0.0 and score_float <= 1.0
    if score_float < 0.6:
        print 'F'
    elif score_float >= 0.6 and score_float < 0.7 :
        print 'D'
    elif score_float >= 0.7 and score_float < 0.8 :
        print 'C'
    elif score_float >= 0.8 and score_float < 0.9 :
        print 'B'
    else:
        print 'A'    
except:
print 'Error, the score has to be a float number between 0.0 and 1.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing a float value with comparison operators doesn't raise an exception, so your exception handler is never reached. The `if` statement is simply false and that branch is not selected.

Either raise an exception manually (using `raise ValueError('Value out of range')` or handle that case explicitly with another `print`.

The only statement that you need to care about raising an exception is the `float()` function call. You should really limit your handler to that statement *only*, and *only* catch the `ValueError` exception that is raised when input is given that is not a float. You can combine the range check at that point to only have one print statement:

```
score = raw_input('Enter score: ')

try:
    score_float = float(score)
    if not (0.0 <= score_float <= 1.0):
        raise ValueError('Number out of range')
except ValueError:
    print 'Error, please enter a valid number between 0.0 and 1.0'
else:
    if score_float < 0.6:
        print 'F'
    elif 0.6 >= score_float < 0.7:
        print 'D'
    elif score_float < 0.8:
        print 'C'
    elif score_float < 0.9:
        print 'B'
    else:
        print 'A'
```

I simplified your tests; you don't need to test for a lower bound that earlier `if` and `elif` tests have already discounted.

You could use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to make translating the float value to a letter simpler:

```
import bisect

names = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
values = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, float('inf')]
print names[bisect.bisect(values, score_float)]
```

Because `1.0` is *included* in the values that map to `'A'` for bisection to work correctly, I used infinity to match the last entry.

Demo:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> names = ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
>>> values = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, float('inf')]
>>> bisect.bisect(values, 0.72)
2
>>> names[bisect.bisect(values, 0.72)]
'C'
>>> bisect.bisect(values, 0.9)
4
>>> names[bisect.bisect(values, 0.9)]
'A'
```